# LWIP -- using option `SO_BINDTODEVICE` with `lwip_setsockopt()` returns error `ENODEV`

Tags: c++, c, lwip, setsockopt

With LWIP, I usually set up my ethernet interface on my embedded device like this *(not all argument definitions are specified here)*:

```cpp
struct netif gnetif;

// Set up the ethernet interface on embedded device.
netif_add(&gnetif, &ipaddr, &netmask, &gw, NULL, &ethernetif_init, &tcpip_input);

// Registers the default network interface.
netif_set_default(&gnetif);

// Make ethernet interface work.
if(netif_is_link_up(&gnetif)){
    netif_set_up(&gnetif);
}
else{
    netif_set_down(&gnetif);
}
```

When the interface is set up, I want to bind it to the device using this call to `setsockopt()`:

```cpp
lwip_setsockopt(int s, int level, int optname, const void *optval, socklen_t optlen)
```

where:

1. `s` is my socket descriptor,
2. `level` is set to `SOL_SOCKET`,
3. `optname` is set to `SO_BINDTODEVICE`,
4. `optval` is a pointer to `ifreq` structure,
5. `optlen` is size of the `ifreq` structure *(previous bullet)*.

This call successfully enters [this](https://github.com/particle-iot/lwip/blob/832490eec8ca35bad435fec104512cfbdaf994bf/src/api/sockets.c#L3311) `switch` statement and successfully interprets the `SOL_SOCKET` level and `SO_BINDTODEVICE` option to end up [here](https://github.com/particle-iot/lwip/blob/832490eec8ca35bad435fec104512cfbdaf994bf/src/api/sockets.c#L3416).

But for some reason [this](https://github.com/particle-iot/lwip/blob/832490eec8ca35bad435fec104512cfbdaf994bf/src/api/sockets.c#L3423) call to `netif_find()` sets `n` to `0` and then I get an error `ENODEV` which means that there is no device. This is weird, because `gnetif.name` returns `st` and also `optval` which is `ifreq` structure has only one member `ifr_name` which looks like this in the debugger *(just before the call)*:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong that I get the `ENDOV` error?